# GCC Cross Compiler for linux under msys2

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, msys2

I'm looking for a cross compiler to compile for linux under the msys2 environment.

I'm looking for somethink like `x86_64-w64-linux-gcc`. But I can't find it.

Which package I have to install?

Comment: I don't  think you can cross compile for linux using mingw  i.e. msys, cygwin etc. If you need to you can use WSL. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl As well as you can use Docker it is also using WSL.

Comment: @VictorGubin What would keep you from cross-compiling? You may have to bootstrap your own toolchain if it isn't pre-packaged though, but are there principal problems preventing it?

Comment: @Peter - Reinstate Monica
You'll need to link with GNU LIBC, MinGW uses MSV CRT or Universal CRT as well as MinGW replacement's for Windows SDK. Compiler generate references to some internal structures etc. You'll faced with many problems, event when you try. On other hand Windows subsystem for Linux give you native GCC with GNU libc etc and it will work with minimal overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a VM or a Linux machine to test the resulting binaries, so I'd just compile on one in the first place.

But cross-compilation should be possible too:

- Boot up your favorite Linux distribution in a VM.
- Install the libraries you want to have. Install `g++` to get libstdc++, and possibly other basic libraries.
- Copy the root directory `/` from the VM to the Windows machine.

  You only need headers and libraries, not everything. You'll have to experiment to know what directories can or can't be safely removed.
- Install Clang on the Windows machine. Installing LLD is also a good idea (it's a separate package in MSYS2; or, if you're using the official Clang binaries, it's bundled with them).

  We're using Clang, because it's inherently a cross-compiler, i.e. doesn't require separate binaries to target a different platform, unlike GCC.
- Compile with Clang with `--target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --sysroot=path/to/root/directory`.

  `-fuse-ld=lld` is probably a good idea as well.

  The string `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` was obtained by running `clang++ --version` on a Linux machine.

You might need a few more flags, but this should be a good starting point.